# sshfs under autofs from Debian 10.9 to macOS 11.0 fails, but sshfs without autofs from and to same works fine

Tags: unix, ssh

I am attempting to set up autofs to spawn an sshfs.

The autofs is on a Debian 10.9 system.

The remote sshd I want it to connect to is on a mac running Big Sur.

When I try to ls the intended (auto)mountpoint, I just get:
No such file or directory

I can ssh in fine, without a password, both as myself and as root.  I want the sshfs to use root.

I changed /etc/ssh/sshd_config to allow root login with a password.  Other than that, the mac's sshd is untweaked.

Also, this works fine on the Debian system:

```
$ sshfs root@daniels-mac-mini:/System/Volumes/Data /mnt
$ ls /mnt
<files>
```

...making it even more weird that sshfs isn't working but only when attempted under autofs.

If I look in the mac's logs, I see a lot of:

```
comp.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.openssh.sshd...): Service exited with abnormal code: 255
```

And if I use launchctl to shut down the sshd on the mac, and then run:

```
/usr/sbin/sshd -d
```

...in a terminal, I get a lot of output, including (retyped, I don't have cut and paste happy yet) :

```
attempt 6 failures 5 [preauth]
Failed password for root from 192.168.1.96 port 33336 ssh2
maximum authentication attempts exceeded for root form 192.168.1.96 port 33336 ssh2 [preauth]
Disconnecting authenticating user root 192.168.1.96 port 33336: Too many authentication failures [preauth]
```

...which is strange, because it should be using public key authentication, not a password.  I know passwordless is working fine in other circumstances between these two hosts.

I've tried a number of things in /etc/auto.mymount on the Debian system, from complex but well-explored-in-Linux-land to as simple as:

```
daniels-mac-mini -fstype=fuse,allow_other :sshfs\#root@daniels-mac-mini\:/System/Volumes/Data
```

Any suggestions folks?  I'm about out of ideas.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It turned out I had forgotten to ssh to root@localhost on the Debian system prior to ssh-copy-id'ing to root@daniels-mac-mini.  ssh-copy-id doesn't like it when you just sudo bash instead of actually ssh'ing.